# Permanent port forwarding

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

I'm doing port forwarding this way:

```
ssh -f user1@11.22.33.44 -L 1234:127.0.0.1:1234 -N
```

It's not permanent, that is, when I close terminal, it's gone and next time I have to call this command again. How to make it permanent?

In particular, I want to run it on a remote server.

Answer (score 3):

To make it ignore the HUP signal all processes get sent when the owning shell closes, invoke the command with prepending `nohup`, like so:

```
nohup ssh -f user1@11.22.33.44 -L 1234:127.0.0.1:1234 -N
```

Comment: ok. and if I run it on a remote server, will that still work?

Comment: @user7863932 Yes, it will.  You may have to redirect in- and output, like so: `nohup sh -c "ssh -f user1@11.22.33.44 -L 1234:127.0.0.1:1234 -N" < /dev/null > /dev/null 2>&1 &`

Comment: but it works even without nohup. I disconnect and connect again and it still works. why?

Answer (score 0):

At remote server, you can always start 'screen' where you put that ssh to run.

And there is 'disown' command what you can use to detach (works like nohup) process. Difference is that, with nohup you need to know beforehand that you want to disconnect process. With disown you can disconnect any process.

Comment: Disown works on jobs, not processes, so you would have to first run a command, then background it and finally disown the job (-h being the same as nohup). Unfortunately, ssh -f forks and exits, which means that it is no longer on your job list, thus you cannot disown it.

Comment: Rabban, It works with ssh very well.  ssh -L1234:127.0.0.1:30000 prod-server & disown, but you must use keys of course because you cannot answer to password query